Loopback filter : COALESCE
I have a SQL query like this
SELECT name, Id, code, date 
FROM Mytable 
WHERE code = 'A1' 
  AND date BETWEEN '2023-07-01' AND '2024-06-25'
  AND (name = COALESCE('MyinputName', name));

I want to pass this where condition to my loop back API in filter.
Is there any way to use COALESCE in loopback API filter?
